# Как отправить UserName конкретному пользователю через Telegram bot (C#)

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

**Задача, сбор заявок.**

Когда пользователь нажимает на inline кнопку "Заявка", то его UserName отправляется конкретному пользователю (менеджеру по сбору заявок).

**Не могу понять как реализовать отправку сообщения конкретному пользователю/менеджеру.**

**Код самих кнопок и их обработка:**

```
private static async void BotOnMessageBack (object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.CallbackQueryEventArgs e)
        {

            var message = e.CallbackQuery.Message;
            string name = $"{message.From.FirstName} {message.From.LastName}";
            string nameUsers = $"{message.From.Username}";

            if (e.CallbackQuery.Data == "callback1")
                {
                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id,
@"<b>Мы приняли Вашу заявку!</b>

В ближайшее время с Вами свяжется наш менеджер. 

Спасибо за ожидание!

Для возврата меню нажмите /start", ParseMode.Html);

                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Username, "platonoof");


                // сюда то что тебе нужно сделать при нажатии на первую кнопку 
            }
                else
                if (e.CallbackQuery.Data == "callback2")
                {
                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id,
@"<b>База СТАРТ</b> - 4.000 руб. (до 1 000 контактов)

<b>База МАКСИМУМ</b> - от 7.000 руб. более 1.000 контактов, поддержка 24/7, гарантия результата!

Для возврата меню нажмите /start", ParseMode.Html); // сюда то что нужно сделать при нажатии на вторую кнопку
            }
                else
                if (e.CallbackQuery.Data == "callback3")
            {
                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id,
@"<b>SMS рассылка</b> 
помогает поддерживать связь с потенциальным клиентом, информировать об акциях и сообщать срочные новости.

<b>Email рассылка</b> 
это идеальный вариант для рассылки коммерческих предложений потенциальным клиентам!

<b>Прозвон роботом</b> 
подходит для проведения опросов, выявления потребностей и заинтересованность клиента к вашему продукту/услуге.

<b>Обзвон потенциальных клиентов</b> 
Отличный вариант для живого общения с потенциальным клиентом. Идеальный инструмент для продажников и колл-центров!

Для возврата меню нажмите /start", ParseMode.Html); // сюда то что нужно сделать при нажатии на вторую кнопку
            }
                else
                if (e.CallbackQuery.Data == "callback4")
            {
                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id,
@"<b>Сайт:</b> big-base.ru
<b>Связь с менеджером:</b> @platonoof

Для возврата меню нажмите /start", ParseMode.Html); // сюда то что нужно сделать при нажатии на вторую кнопку
            }
        }



        private static async void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            var message = e.Message;
            if (message == null)
                return;

            string name = $"{message.From.FirstName} {message.From.LastName}";
            string nameUsers = $"{message.Chat.Username}";

            Console.WriteLine($"{name} send message: '{message.Text}'");


            switch (message.Text)
            {
                case "/start":
                    var inlineKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
                    {
                        new[]
                        {
                            InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Заявка", "callback1"),
                            InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Цены", "callback2")
                        },
                        new[]
                        {
                            InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Для Чего?", "callback3"),
                            InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Контакты", "callback4")
                        }
                    });
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                        message.From.Id,

@"<b>Здравствуйте</b> 

Если Вам интересны наши услуги, Вы можете оставить заявку и узнать цены из меню ниже.

Воспользуйтесь Меню ниже.", 

                        ParseMode.Html,
                        replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard);
                    break;

            }

            
          

        }
```

Comment: Нужно создать с этим конкретным пользователем чат (я это делал руками), прописать ID чата в настройки/константы и писать в этот чат как в обычный чат.

Comment: А есть пример кода?

Comment: Да там одна строчка, что приводить-то? `this.Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(new ChatId(MainChatId), text, replyMarkup: ikm, cancellationToken: CancellationToken);` подключен пакет `<PackageReference Include="Telegram.Bot" Version="15.7.1" />`

Comment: Я сделал так. Получил ChatId - `string nameUsers = $"{message.Chat.Username}";` А после обработки нажатия на кнопку `long chatId = тут нужный id; await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, nameUsers);`

Comment: Ну вот видите - действительно ничего сложного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решил следующим образом:**

*Перед обработкой*

```
string nameUsers = $"{message.Chat.Username}";
```

*После обработки нажатия на кнопку*

```
long chatId = тут нужный chatId;

await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, nameUsers);
```